# Looking for a scene where Jet Black applies a chokehold to a man and asks "tell me some more"

Tags: cowboy-bebop

I am looking for said scene. Already tried downloading all the subtitles and searching, and also asking chatGPT, but no success.

I believe the scene exists, and is the one on the first image of from [this page](https://karmaburn.com/?cat=49):

[image: Jet black chokeholding a man]

Anyone remembers it?

I watched the show multiple times, and will probably watch it again some day, but right now I am looking for this specific scene to make a meme, so an episode number and timestamp would be rather helpful

Comment: Have you tried watching the show?

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: I do not view this question as being unclear in what it is asking. You want the episode number and a timestamp of when this scene happens in the episode, presumably?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Will add the clarification to the question

Comment: ChatGPT is pretty bad at these things. I tried to search on trace.moe but it didn't identify correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This moment occurs around the 11:10 to 11:14 mark in the first episode, *Asteroid Blues*. For the time reference, I was using the English dub episode on Crunchyroll.

The scene: Jet walks into a ransacked saloon, takes a bottle of alcohol, but hides when two men enter. After listening to the two talk about the guy using Red Eye drug, Jet assaults the two and puts one in the choke hold with the broken bottle to his throat, and says, "Tell me some more."

I also seemed to recall this moment being used in promotional material by Toonami, and this compilation video would seem to indicate my recollection was correct: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIYX401Ubjc